# TO increase php upload file size limit

Tags: php, file, limit

we need to overwrite php.ini file

ans is provided in my 1st comment
I tried a lot of things and come in conclusion that how can i do in Lamp stack on uubuntu 22

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to edit `php.ini` file, you can just modify the following parameters

`upload_file_maxsize` and `post_max_size` to your preferred value.

if not, use `ini_set()` function at start of your php script, for example

```
ini_set("upload_file_maxsize", "200MB");
```

Comment: Not working on integrating with Drupal

Comment: after changing your values in php.ini file, server restart is required. have you restarted your server?

Comment: Yup, I restarted the server